# Discord.js, Problem with reconlx button pages

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to make an help page for my bot, which has pages, that are switched with Discord Buttons, to do it I used reconlx package, but after I run the bot, the console says:

```
/home/runner/Nightcorer-4/node_modules/reconlx/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [`discord.js`](https://npmjs.com/package/discord.js) requires node version `16.0.0` or higher. Update your node version by going to [the official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) and reinstalling the latest version of `node.js`.

Comment: @Tyler2P I updated node to the latest version, but the problem is still the same, I might need to edit that line in the Reconlx package, but I dont know how to

Comment: Run `node -v` in your projects terminal and make sure it states `16.0.0` or above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update Node.js to v16.0.0 .

If You aren't sure about the Node version installed, run this command on terminal:

```
node -v
```

You can download the new Node.js version [here](https://nodejs.org/).